# "Table exists" step in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I want to use "Table exists" step to check if certain table exists if not then create one

The transformation I have created (in order to copy data from input database into output database)

```
Table Input ----->  Table exists  ----> Table output
```

The properties in "Table exists" are

```
Step name:
connection:
Schema name:

Tablename field:
Result fieldname:
```

The first three are clear. The last two

What does "Tablename field" mean ? It is a drop list with limited options which are column names of input table. Should it be the table name I want to check in connection ?

What is Result fieldname ? How can I use that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `Tablename` field is the table it checks for.
- `Result fieldname` The name of the field that will contain the
  boolean result flag in the output of this step.

Use the following sequence to check and create table if not exist.

[image]

Table Input - Get the data in, from the database.

Generate rows - Specify `tablenamefield` as name and `table_name_to_check` as value and `String` as type.  Later we can use the field `tablenamefield` in Table exists step

Table Exist - Select `tablenamefield` which appears in the Tablename field drop down. Write any name as the `Result fieldname` i.e `result`

Switch/ Case - Type `Y` in case values and `Table Output` as the target step. Make `execute SQL statement` as Default target step. field name to switch is `result`

Execute SQL statement - Write your table creation SQL query.

Table Output - Writes to the new table.

**NB:** If you don't want to check whether the table exist for each row. you can use a job and check for the table existence in first transformation and Table input and output steps in second transformation which I recommend for performance.

Comment: thanks for the response. In my spoon, Table input can not hop to Generate Rows

Comment: Any error? If not you can generate a constant field in your query in Table input like SELECT field1, field2, 'tablename' as tablenamefield from table. So that you dont need to use Generate Rows step

Answer (score 0):

the `Tablename` field is the field that contains the name of the table(s) you want to check. If you only want to check a single table, you only need a single row with the table name in one of the fields.

The `Result fieldname` is the name of a new field the step is going to add to the step output. That new field contains the result of the check. It is a `boolean` field you can then use in later steps, for instance to send this row into a branch that creates the table. The field value is `true` if the table exists and `false` if the table doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am not allowed to fill in the name of table I want to check, it is a drop list with limited options which are column names of the table I want to check. Is that possible that I have connected the steps in a wrong way ?

Comment: no. This is how ETL steps usually work - they take their parameters from fields. So your "check table"-step is executed for every single row in your transformation and it receives the table name from a row in its input. You can't manually enter a field name in the step.